# javascript new date creation error

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

In my app i am trying to create new date in javascript. Datetime returned from server is in following format:

```
 септембар, 25 2013 19:40:44
```

I have tried to create date using new Date() and also Date.parse, both of them failed. new Date() gives me Invalid Date, and Date.parse gives me NaN. Any suggestions?

Comment: септембар translates to 'Septembar' in English. There isn't a misspelling is there?

Comment: no, septembar is in my language. but i think that the comma is the problem here, becouse new Date accepts Septembar 25, 2013 19:40:44, but not this Septembar, 25 2013 19:40:44

Comment: Yes, it's probably a misspell, but it doesn't even parse it when correctly changed to септембeр

Comment: comma is the problem, i do not why that comma is there

Comment: What language is the server written in? Did you write the server? What is the code that is displaying the date like that?

Comment: I think the problem is the language used itself(for a problem of charset I guess), not the comma

Comment: Server language is in English, and i select date from db. In my db date looks like this 2013-09-25 19:40:44, but when i pass it to the client via JSON i get the above date

Comment: I mean what programming language is the server? What code is used to pass it to the client via JSON? In other words, how are you getting from  2013-09-30 19:40:44 to септембар, 25 2013 19:40:44?

Comment: Server code is written in ColdFusion, and i do nothing to get that date. My function has returnFormat set to JSON and when i return result from db to client i get that date

Comment: I think @eliot is correct, the [MDN specification page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) nor the [RFC Date Specs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14) mention support for multilingual month value

Comment: Is there any way to remove septembar via formating? I have tried many ways to format date in CF but on client i always get month name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my console,

`new Date('Septembar, 25 2013 19:40:44')`

returns

`Wed Sep 25 2013 19:40:44 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

but

`new Date('септембар, 25 2013 19:40:44')`

returns

`Invalid Date`

JavaScript must not support that charset and you will have to convert it before passing it as a parameter.

Comment: @Pavlo Do you know what language it is? I pasted it into Google Translate and that was the detected language.

Comment: @Pavlo is it Vietnamese?

Comment: @eliot No, Vietnamese doesn't use Cyrillic alphabet. Looks like [Serbian](http://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80), but I don't know why OP can't just tell us.

Comment: Is there any way to remove septembar via formating? I have tried many ways to format date in CF but on client i always get month name